# Why I am getting error "SQL command not properly ended"?

Tags: sql

Here is the SQL query I am trying to run in oracle live SQL:

```
SELECT yearly,branch,SUM(package_offered) AS "PACKAGE_OFFERED"
FROM PLACEMENT_FACTS AS PAF ,STUDENT AS ST, TIME_PERIOD AS TP
WHERE PAF.STUDENT_ID = ST.STUDENT_ID AND PAF.TIME_PERIOD_ID = TP.TIME_PERIOD_ID AND BRANCH = 'MECH'
GROUP BY yearly;
```

Comment: And why aren't you using `JOIN`?  Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to write this query is something like this:

```
SELECT yearly, branch, SUM(package_offered) AS PACKAGE_OFFERED
FROM PLACEMENT_FACTS PAF JOIN
     STUDENT ST
     ON PAF.STUDENT_ID = ST.STUDENT_ID JOIN
     TIME_PERIOD TP
     ON PAF.TIME_PERIOD_ID = TP.TIME_PERIOD_ID
WHERE BRANCH = 'MECH'
GROUP BY yearly, branch;
```

You should qualify `yearly` and `branch` so it is clear what tables they come from.

Notes:

- *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.
- You don't need to escape the column alias.
- You should qualify all column names.
- All the unaggregated columns in the `SELECT` should be in the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Thanks, it works. I need to understand the working of the GROUP BY Clause.